# Satisfying a Condition Among List of Lists of Arbitrary Length

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of numbers of arbitrary length.

For example:

```
a = [[3,17,19,4],[4,18,10,1],[11,15,13],[7,9,12,16]]
```

The level of nesting is restricted to this depth.

I want to find all lists whose first element comes from the first inner list, whose second element comes from the second inner list, and so on, such that this new list's elements are all increasing.

Based on the given example, [4, 10, 11, 12] is one such list.

I'm struggling in that I would like the solution to be generic, independent of how many inner lists there are.

If I were guaranteed four inner lists, I could naively code:

```
for w in a[0]:
    for x in a[1]:
        for y in a[2]:
            for z in a[3]:
                if w < x < y < z:
                    print [w,x,y,z]
```

But if I add a fifth inner list, or remove the fourth inner list above, I'm out of luck.

How can I generate all monotonically increasing "sublists", no matter how many inner lists are in the main list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def combine(lists, peak=None):
  if not lists:
    yield []
  else:
    for i in lists[0]:
      if peak is None or i > peak:
        for tail in combine(lists[1:], i):
          yield [ i ] + tail

for x in combine([[3,17,19,4],[4,18,10,1],[11,15,13],[7,9,12,16]]): print x

[3, 4, 11, 12]
[3, 4, 11, 16]
[3, 4, 15, 16]
[3, 4, 13, 16]
[3, 10, 11, 12]
[3, 10, 11, 16]
[3, 10, 15, 16]
[3, 10, 13, 16]
[4, 10, 11, 12]
[4, 10, 11, 16]
[4, 10, 15, 16]
[4, 10, 13, 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance isn't a concern, you can use `itertools.product` and loop over all possibilities, e.g.

```
from itertools import product

def is_increasing(seq):
    return all(x < y for x,y in zip(seq[:-1], seq[1:]))
```

after which

```
>>> a = [[3,17,19,4],[4,18,10,1],[11,15,13],[7,9,12,16]]
>>> [k for k in product(*a) if is_increasing(k)]
[(3, 4, 11, 12), (3, 4, 11, 16), (3, 4, 15, 16), 
(3, 4, 13, 16), (3, 10, 11, 12), (3, 10, 11, 16), 
(3, 10, 15, 16), (3, 10, 13, 16), (4, 10, 11, 12), 
(4, 10, 11, 16), (4, 10, 15, 16), (4, 10, 13, 16)]
```

[The comment about performance isn't because `itertools.product` is itself slow, just that if you do it this way you have to search over every possibility even if you could have ruled it out earlier with a smarter algorithm.]